# Custom Laravel 5.1 Middleware Logic

Tags: php, laravel

I'm stuck in this issue where I'm facing problem setting up my custom middleware in Laravel 5.1

Here's what I want.

I want user to go through setup steps when He logs in to my app.
If he completes the setup he should not see that setup page again.
Also I'm setting this middleware in global array.

here's my middleware.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;

class SetupMiddleware
{


    /**
     * The Guard implementation.
     *
     * @var Guard
     */
    protected $auth;

    /**
     * Create a new filter instance.
     *
     * @param  Guard  $auth
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Guard $auth)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }


    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        if($this->auth->check()){


            if( $this->auth->user()->active == false ){

                if ($request->ajax())
                {
                    return response('Not verified.', 401);
                }
                else
                {
                    return redirect('/user/verification');
                }

            }



            if( $this->auth->user()->active != false &&  null === Auth::user()->school ){

                if ($request->ajax())
                {
                    return response('Not allowed.', 401);
                }
                else
                {
                    return redirect('/setup/info');
                }

            }



            if( $this->auth->user()->active != false &&  null !== Auth::user()->school &&  $this->auth->user()->payment_active == false ){

                if ($request->ajax())
                {
                    return response('Not allowed.', 401);
                }
                else
                {
                    return redirect('/setup/payment');
                }

            }



            if( $this->auth->user()->active != false && null !== Auth::user()->school &&  $this->auth->user()->payment_active != false ){


                return $next($request);

            }

            return $next($request);
        }


        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Also he shouldn't see the step which is already completed. Suppose if user has created the related model "school" he should be redirected to 'setup/payement' url instead of 'setup/info'. right now I can login and visit every step even when I have completed all the steps.

Manually redirecting to each step if the condition matches is the only option I see so far but that approach makes my controller too muddy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem like you understand the programming flow.
If you do `$this->auth->user()->active == false` theres no need to do `$this->auth->user()->active != false` as if it would have false it would have returned a redirect header.
Same thing for all your other conditions.

Now to handle the actual issue ,instead of using a `middleware` you should use form-request approach and then by [session](http://laravel.com/docs/master/session) save the user current step and redirect him by the data you get from session.[should create sort of a helper to handle the actual routes redirecting]

Comment: Actually these steps should be completed before user sees the actual dashboard of application. So I solved the issue by manually verifying it in Controller. I found no other way. By the way I tried the other part you have described  in first paragraph that doesn't seems to be helpful enough. That approach also had the same problem.

Comment: Well of course there are many ways to accomplish this but putting everything under controller making it look messy. About the first paragraph its not about making it work its about programming flow,you creating useless if conditions which can be removed.